# Performing transactions of fanned-out data in Firebase

Tags: firebase, firebase-realtime-database, nosql

I am working on creating a social network-esque feed, and have been following the [guide](https://firebase.googleblog.com/2015/10/client-side-fan-out-for-data-consistency_73.html) on the Firebase blog on fanning out my "blog posts" across the database.

This makes sense and works well for interacting with these posts using the update() method. However, it is unclear to me how I could go about performing transactions atomically in multiple places.

For example, I want to add the ability to 'like' a post. If I were to have that post in one location, my code would look like so:

```
var postRef = firebaseDB.ref("posts/" + postID + "/likes");
postRef.transaction(function(likes) {
    return (likes || 0) + 1;
});
```

For obvious reasons, the solution below is **not** atomic.

```
var postRef1 = firebaseDB.ref("posts/" + postID + "/likes");
postRef1.transaction(function(likes) {
    return (likes || 0) + 1;
});

var postRef2 = firebaseDB.ref("user/" + userID + "/posts/" + postID + "/likes");
postRef2.transaction(function(likes) {
    return (likes || 0) + 1;
});
```

Since transaction operates on a ref, how can I "like" the posts in multiple places atomically?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

For your usecase, you need firebase-queue with [throttle on the client](https://gist.github.com/leblancmeneses/16274598b3a2da9c9566ef7e672a94be) when writing to the queue task's node.

Your fan out occurs in the worker node where you can build the compensation model based on promise success/failure.

queue is the only way to guarantee the work is completed and simplifies your client code.

Reference: [ways to live without transactions](https://docs.particular.net/nservicebus/azure/ways-to-live-without-transactions)

=========

Edit: March 2017 Cloud functions for Firebase was introduced and is now the recommended way to implement fan-out.

Comment: How about setting firebase queue (which is admin) to only handle 1 task at a time, in addition to disallowing users from editing such fields.
This means only one is updating the data, so no ned for transaction.
Of course this is not much scalable but it works.
@Leblanc Meneses

Comment: @MuhammadHassan firebase-queue guarantees each queued item will be processed only once by 1 worker.   This approach scales easily because of how producer-consumer model works.  Adding more workers will horizontally scale.

Comment: I understand, but may be another worker who is working on another task edits the same node which can cause a problem.
Since we can run a transaction on multiple paths in firebase I see that the only option is to limit the number of workers to 1, that way we can avoid transaction.
What do you think?

Comment: Writing to the same node means you are might be modeling your data incorrectly.  Each module of your system should be 100% independent of the other modules. Writing features should be additive and not require modifying your existing features. With the recent announcements, it is now easier to implement fan-out using cloud functions for Firebase.